# How to auto-populate custom field in a SharePoint Modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog

I am having some difficulty auto-populating a field in a SharePoint Modal dialog. When the dialog appears, I want the text box to be automatically set with a value. Like this:

[image]

None of these columns are default. I created a list, and then created these fields afterwards. Each are used in "Item". Then I tied the list to this dialog. Also, I went into the list settings and choose "
Allow management of content types". The default column is hidden.

One of the problems is that I'm not sure if I need to pass the value to the options object to set the value in the text box.

Here is the code I am currently trying. I've tested it in IE 8, 9 and 10, and also in Chrome 39. The field I want to populate when the dialog opens is always blank in each, however.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");  
var context = null;  
var web = null;  
var currentUser = null;  

function getWebUserData() 
{  
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    web = context.get_web();  
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();  
    currentUser.retrieve();  
    context.load(web);  
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));  
}    

function ContactUsOpenDialog(strPageURL)
{
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser(); 
    var options = 
    {
        title: "Contact Us",
        width: 750,
        height: 550,
        url: strPageURL
        //args: "Subject"
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name*="Subject"]').val("The field is set for the user");
    })

    // I also tried this
    //$("input[Item='Subject']").val("The field is set for the user");

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
```

This is how I render the dialog via html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ContactUsOpenDialog(&#39;http://site...com/Lists/Contact Us/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=&#39;);">
<p class="fontStyle">Contact Us</p>
</a>​
```

Any ideas what is wrong, or how I can auto-populate the Subject custom field in the dialog?

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions? Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I expect that JavaScript you show is in the page from which you open newform.aspx and not in newform.aspx itself.

In that case javascript will not work because $(document).ready function is fired when current page is fully loaded.Not the modaldialog page.

Functional way would be put function setting textbox value in newform.aspx. The most simple way is contenteditortwebpart. Or you can update the form by SharePoint designer. If you want to set the textbox value only in some circumstances (e.g. when opening form particular page) you can pass parameter to newform.aspx. The most simple way is by URL. Then check the parameter or its value in javascript.

For comfortable setting of SharePoint user controls you can use this [library](http://sputility.codeplex.com/).